# For each loop not working as expected with object

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm looping through an object, and when an object key equals a string, it echoes something. However, it's not working when in an `if statement`.

```
$get_categories = get_categories(); // gets an object (with the key)

foreach ($get_categories as $key) {
    $each_cat = $key->name;
    echo $each_cat; // echoes 'beauty', 'celebrity', 'lifestyle'
    if ($each_cat == 'fashion') { // this is FALSE, even though it prints 'fashion' above
        echo 'Yes, this is the fashion string'; // this does not get printed
    }
}
```

This is the object it's looping through:

```
ARRAY (SIZE=7)
  0 => 
    OBJECT(STDCLASS)[311]
      PUBLIC 'TERM_ID' => &STRING '9' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'NAME' => &STRING 'BEAUTY' (LENGTH=6)
      PUBLIC 'SLUG' => &STRING 'BEAUTY' (LENGTH=6)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_GROUP' => STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_TAXONOMY_ID' => STRING '9' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TAXONOMY' => STRING 'CATEGORY' (LENGTH=8)
      PUBLIC 'DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'COUNT' => &STRING '1' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_ID' => &STRING '9' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_COUNT' => &STRING '1' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_NAME' => &STRING 'BEAUTY' (LENGTH=6)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_NICENAME' => &STRING 'BEAUTY' (LENGTH=6)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
  1 => 
    OBJECT(STDCLASS)[310]
      PUBLIC 'TERM_ID' => &STRING '11' (LENGTH=2)
      PUBLIC 'NAME' => &STRING 'CELEBRITY' (LENGTH=9)
      PUBLIC 'SLUG' => &STRING 'CELEBRITY' (LENGTH=9)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_GROUP' => STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_TAXONOMY_ID' => STRING '11' (LENGTH=2)
      PUBLIC 'TAXONOMY' => STRING 'CATEGORY' (LENGTH=8)
      PUBLIC 'DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'COUNT' => &STRING '3' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_ID' => &STRING '11' (LENGTH=2)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_COUNT' => &STRING '3' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_NAME' => &STRING 'CELEBRITY' (LENGTH=9)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_NICENAME' => &STRING 'CELEBRITY' (LENGTH=9)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
  3 => 
    OBJECT(STDCLASS)[308]
      PUBLIC 'TERM_ID' => &STRING '4' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'NAME' => &STRING 'FASHION' (LENGTH=7)
      PUBLIC 'SLUG' => &STRING 'FASHION' (LENGTH=7)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_GROUP' => STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_TAXONOMY_ID' => STRING '4' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TAXONOMY' => STRING 'CATEGORY' (LENGTH=8)
      PUBLIC 'DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'COUNT' => &STRING '4' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_ID' => &STRING '4' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_COUNT' => &STRING '4' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_NAME' => &STRING 'FASHION' (LENGTH=7)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_NICENAME' => &STRING 'FASHION' (LENGTH=7)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
  5 => 
    OBJECT(STDCLASS)[306]
      PUBLIC 'TERM_ID' => &STRING '10' (LENGTH=2)
      PUBLIC 'NAME' => &STRING 'LIFESTYLE' (LENGTH=9)
      PUBLIC 'SLUG' => &STRING 'LIFESTYLE' (LENGTH=9)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_GROUP' => STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_TAXONOMY_ID' => STRING '10' (LENGTH=2)
      PUBLIC 'TAXONOMY' => STRING 'CATEGORY' (LENGTH=8)
      PUBLIC 'DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'COUNT' => &STRING '3' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_ID' => &STRING '10' (LENGTH=2)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_COUNT' => &STRING '3' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_NAME' => &STRING 'LIFESTYLE' (LENGTH=9)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_NICENAME' => &STRING 'LIFESTYLE' (LENGTH=9)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
  6 => 
    OBJECT(STDCLASS)[305]
      PUBLIC 'TERM_ID' => &STRING '1' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'NAME' => &STRING 'NONE' (LENGTH=4)
      PUBLIC 'SLUG' => &STRING 'NONE' (LENGTH=4)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_GROUP' => STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_TAXONOMY_ID' => STRING '1' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TAXONOMY' => STRING 'CATEGORY' (LENGTH=8)
      PUBLIC 'DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'COUNT' => &STRING '2' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_ID' => &STRING '1' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_COUNT' => &STRING '2' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_NAME' => &STRING 'NONE' (LENGTH=4)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_NICENAME' => &STRING 'NONE' (LENGTH=4)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
  8 => 
    OBJECT(STDCLASS)[303]
      PUBLIC 'TERM_ID' => &STRING '16' (LENGTH=2)
      PUBLIC 'NAME' => &STRING 'TOP' (LENGTH=3)
      PUBLIC 'SLUG' => &STRING 'TOP' (LENGTH=3)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_GROUP' => STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_TAXONOMY_ID' => STRING '16' (LENGTH=2)
      PUBLIC 'TAXONOMY' => STRING 'CATEGORY' (LENGTH=8)
      PUBLIC 'DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'COUNT' => &STRING '2' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_ID' => &STRING '16' (LENGTH=2)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_COUNT' => &STRING '2' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_NAME' => &STRING 'TOP' (LENGTH=3)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_NICENAME' => &STRING 'TOP' (LENGTH=3)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_PARENT' => &STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
  9 => 
    OBJECT(STDCLASS)[302]
      PUBLIC 'TERM_ID' => &STRING '8' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'NAME' => &STRING 'TRENDS' (LENGTH=6)
      PUBLIC 'SLUG' => &STRING 'TRENDS' (LENGTH=6)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_GROUP' => STRING '0' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TERM_TAXONOMY_ID' => STRING '8' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'TAXONOMY' => STRING 'CATEGORY' (LENGTH=8)
      PUBLIC 'DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'PARENT' => &STRING '4' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'COUNT' => &STRING '1' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_ID' => &STRING '8' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_COUNT' => &STRING '1' (LENGTH=1)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION' => &STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      PUBLIC 'CAT_NAME' => &STRING 'TRENDS' (LENGTH=6)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_NICENAME' => &STRING 'TRENDS' (LENGTH=6)
      PUBLIC 'CATEGORY_PARENT' => &STRING '4' (LENGTH=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as

```
foreach ($get_categories as $key=>$val) {
    $each_cat = $val->name;
    echo $each_cat; // echoes 'beauty', 'celebrity', 'lifestyle'
    if ($each_cat == 'fashion') { // this is FALSE, even though it prints 'fashion' above
        echo 'Yes, this is the fashion string'; // this does not get printed
    }
}
```

Here `$key` is the array indexes `0,1,2...`
The `$val` is the corresponding values for those keys which is an Object.

So doing `$key->name` will not return anything in this example.

```
if ($each_cat == 'fashion')
```

block of code is correct as your echo shows they are all in lower case, if you are looking at the variable dump they are all in CAPS including the PUBLIC, Key name etc. They should not get capitalized.

Comment: 'FASHION' != 'fashion'

try: `if (strtolower($each_cat) == 'fashion') {`

Comment: Yes good point the case sensitivity needs to be taken care as well !!

Comment: The string to lower works. But to reverse it, `$each_cat == 'FASHION'` returns false?

Comment: Can u double check if its not in lower in the returned array ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand? If the array is returning an uppercase 'FASHION', how come if I compare it to the string 'FASHION' it returns false? But by making the array lowercase, it can be compared to 'fashion'?

Comment: well you took a var_dump() and not sure how they are all shown as caps, just try `print_r($get_categories);`

Comment: Ah, that shows the name has a capital letter at the beginning. That would be why, thanks!